# What does "it goes with the flow" mean in relation to CSS floats and negative margins?

Tags: html, css

I have used `float:left` and `right` a few times.

Still I don't understand what it means when a book says "it goes with the flow" or "it breaks the flow".

For example:

> **It goes with the flow**
>
> It does not break the flow of the page if applied to elements without floats. So if you use a negative margin to nudge an element upwards, all succeeding elements will be nudged as well.

(From http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

What does this mean?

Comment: Sounds like a crappy book.

Comment: Some context would be nice

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Haha! I found an even older article

Comment: @mplungjan: Doesn't contain the exact phrasing given in the newer article though. Instead it says "taken out of normal flow" etc which actually makes sense - the phrasing that is given here is meaningless in CSS.

Comment: My article explains their use of flow

Comment: ok.. so what does it mean "taken out of normal flow" ???

Comment: [Normal Flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)

Answer (score 0):

See this:

> Block level elements make boxes in the flow. They are always a solid,
>   regular, rectangular shape. This is why you can give them a border,
>   width and height without the browser worrying about funny shapes.
>   Inline level elements don’t make this lovely regular shapes: They
>   could start of regular, but then flow next to a box on the left and be
>   forced over to the right. Here’s a diagram:
>
> As you can see, the inline level element (the text) is all over the
>   place! It has to worm its way between the block level elements. To
>   enable the browser to render this, the inline text is split into ‘line
>   boxes’: a sort of block level box that contains the text of the
>   current line, that doesn’t really exist and can be places next to
>   other block level elements. The line boxes in the diagram above have
>   been outlines in a light blue. So block level elements form nice boxes
>   in the flow, inline ones don’t. It’s also worth noting that block
>   level elements cannot appear next to each other: they will always be
>   on different lines, even if you constrain their widths so they could
>   appear next to each other (this is unless you invoke the float model
>   or positioned model, which I’ll come onto later)

http://xmouse.ithium.net/2004/what-is-the-flow

Comment: That's not really a good description of Normal Flow. The idea that a line-box is "sort of block-level box" is simply incorrect.